# CMake skip install under Linux

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm very new to cmake, and in my cmake script(3.12) it happens, that the following commands are executed fine under windows

```
  add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES}) 
  install(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME} DESTINATION lib)
```

but under linux (mint 17.2) the install routine is skipped and the lib folder is empty after calling make.

**Q**: What has to be changed, that lib.a is copied to the lib folder.

**EDIT:**
    The `LIB_NAME` is created as follow

```
SET(PROJECT_NAME_STR System)
SET(LIB_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME_STR}_s")
```

Comment: Your target here is from a variable `LIB_NAME`. Could you show us how this variable is assigned to its value ? Not too sure about this, but I can't see a reason why the target's name should be dynamically set.

Answer (score 1):

Might well be that you do not have write permissions in the install target folder. What's the value of the destination variable and how are your permissions for that target?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the "problem" myself. And now is the moment where you can throw tomatoes at me.

I forgot to call make install.

Sorry.